# Difference between GetGetMethod method and GetMethod property?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, getter-setter, accessor, propertyinfo

.Net 4.5 has [PropertyInfo.GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod.aspx) as a property on `PropertyInfo` class. Is it doing anything different from `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod` method? The documentation page is virtually blank. The only difference I can find is `GetGetMethod` by default returns only public getter while `GetMethod` returns even non-public getter (the same is achieved by `GetGetMethod(true)`).

Similarly there is `GetSetMethod` method and `SetMethod` property in .NET 4.5. Why was it introduced in .NET?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no difference. The property `GetMethod` calls `GetGetMethod` to get the getter. <sup>1</sup> Here's what ILSpy tells me about the property implementation:

```
// System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public virtual MethodInfo GetMethod
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return this.GetGetMethod(true);
    }
}
```

The property `GetMethod` is simply easier to use, because it does not relate on an parameter.

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>Never thought I could use the word *get* so many times in just one sentence!</sup></sub>

Comment: +1 for making me laugh with the sentence `The property GetMethod calls GetGetMethod to get the getter.`